# Form String From .txt file without using System.IO Class in VB

Tags: vb.net

I would like to know whether there is a way to convert the text from a .txt file to a string without using the System.IO Class in VB 2010. Thank you.

Comment: Luckily the Encoding class is in the System.Text namespace.  It makes very little sense to intentionally avoid System.IO.StreamReader, without explaining why anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just after a quick way to read in a file, try:

```
Dim strJunk As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\Junk\Junk.txt")
```